# Copy data from one table of one database to onother table of other database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hello i know that are answers about my question but i cannot figure it out. So i need help. I have to databases, Database A and B.

```
Database A has structure
table AT and columns 
A1
A2
A3
A4

Database B has structure
table BT and columns
B1
B2
B3
B4
```

how i can make the query to copy all the data from database B and table BT to database A and table AT?

i now is something like

```
select * into [databaseTo].dbo.tablename from [databaseFrom].dbo.tablename
```

but i don't know how to right it. 
Thank you

Comment: Your example shows T-SQL syntax, of MS SQL Server, but you tagged mysql and phpmyadmin. What are you using?

Comment: phpmyadmin is for a web project

Comment: Why don't you simply use Database A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then

```
INSERT INTO A.AT (A1, A2, A3, A4)
SELECT B1, B2, B3, B4 
FROM B.BT
```

should do the work. Your MySQL user needs privileges for both databases of course.

Comment: Thanks its worked. i will accept your answer in 5 minutes. thanks again